# How to modify content of an activity from an IntentService that have been started from another activity?

Tags: java, android

Here is my situation:

I want to make an `Activity` A which start an `IntentService`, and write the `ResultReciever` on `Activity` B. In another words, I have an `Activity` A that have some works to do but the results should be written in `Activity` B, any solution to do this? Note that I don't know when the work of the service finishes.

Comment: What's the relationship between Activity A and B?  I'm assuming Activity A starts B at some point?

Comment: Yes, but i can't use onActivityResult() function, because when I close Activity B the service might not been finished yet.

Comment: If B launched A and then A started the service, the service could send back results to B easily. Unfortunately, A launches B. Do you need to use a ResultReceiver? Maybe another mechanism like LocalBroadcastManager would work better.

Comment: Yes I tried LocalBroadcastManager and that worked perfectlly, thnks.